# Can't find "Add" Node

Tags: node-editor, shaders

Maybe it's elementary but I can't find the 'Add' node in Blender 2.82. Maybe you know where it is.

[image: Missing Node]

Comment: Can you please accept the answer on the question?

Answer (score 8):

This node is on converter -> math and then you can enter your operation, in your case add